# Replaced Windows 11 on my HP with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and noticed my headphones no long work

Tags: headphones

Replaced Windows 11 on my HP with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and noticed my headphones no longer play nor does it turn off the computer speaker off when the jack is inserted. Also With the headphones connected if I close the laptop lid and open the it the headphone begin to play ans will work till they are disconnected.

Note: With the lid closed they will play for about one minute and then stop till the lid is reopened.

(Maybe unrelated to the first issue)

I also discovered my Bluetooth devices will not connect = yes when attempting to switch them to on.